# choice based on current entity in ImplicitNamingStrategy.determineBasicColumnName

Tags: java, hibernate

I know a logical schema of a 3rd-party readonly DB and I want to access it with Hibernate 6. I used the schema to generate `@Entity` beans for it, but there's one problem:

Different entities may have identical logical attribute names, but the physical column names are mapped in a special registry table in the same DB and they may differ among entities and even for the same entity in different environments. For instance, on one environment the column is called "name" and on another it's "name2".

To solve this I'm trying to implement one of these two methods:

- `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy.determineBasicColumnName(ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource)`
- `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy.toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier, JdbcEnvironment)`

They are supposed to access the registry table and convert the property accordingly.

However, the caller does not pass the current entity name to the callbacks and I don't know for which entity to retrieve the physical column name!

Is there a workaround better than prefixing all like this? `@Column("MyEntiy$MyProperty")`

Answer (score 1):

I have a class annotated with `@Embeddable` and used as `@Embedded` in fields in many classes or in many fields of the same class. I want to prefix it when mapping with a custom annotation.
But in some specific cases, I may also use `@Convert` mapping. Therefore, even if I follow some agreed naming rules, I cannot simply perform related logic processing through the column name.
During this process, I encountered the same trouble as you: how to obtain the metadata of the Entity class and related fields in the implementation of `ImplicitNamingStrategy` or `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.
Through debugging, I found that the parameters in the interface in the source code implementation, such as `ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource`, are passed in as instances of anonymous classes, so I used the following method to obtain data other than [closure].

```java
    @SneakyThrows
    private AnnotatedColumn getAnnotatedColumn(ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource source) {
        val field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (AnnotatedColumn) field.get(source);
    }
```

After getting the `AnnotatedColumn`, things are simple.
The following is a screenshot of a simple usage fragment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs1Te.png)

It should be noted that different jpa implementations or different versions of specific implementations may obtain different objects. Class like what I got in hibernate5.6 is `Ejb3Column`